# An extremal combinatorics problem

Tags: additive-combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, sidon-sets

Given two integers integers $0<b<p$ and a real $\alpha\in(0,1)$ what is the largest $m$ we have such that in the interval $(p^\alpha,p-p^\alpha)$ there are $m$ integers $a_1<\dots<a_m$ such that

1. $a_i-a_j\neq a_{i'}-a_{j'}$ holds if $i\neq i'$ or $j\neq j'$ or both.
2. $\min_{1\leq i<j\leq m}|a_i-a_j|>b$
   holds?

Comment: Instead of the interval $(p^\alpha,p-p^{\alpha})$ you may consider any interval containing the same number of integers (by shifting). Sets satisfying 1) are called Sidon sets and a lot if known about them. Is there asymptotic relation between $b$ and $p-2p^\alpha$ which you are mostly interested in?

Comment: @FedorPetrov $b\asymp p^\beta$ holds and I am interested in $0<\beta<\alpha$, $\beta=\alpha$ and $\alpha<\beta<1$ regime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking [Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov)'s observation a little further, I believe the right question to ask is as follows: 
  $$ \text{What is the largest size of a $b$-separated Sidon set in the interval $[0,L]$?} $$ 
Here *"$b$-separated"* means that the difference between any two consecutive elements of the set is at least $b+1$.

Clearly, one cannot find in $[0,L]$ a $b$-separated set of size larger than $L/b+1$; on the other hand, taking a large Sidon set in $[0,L/(b+1)]$ and dilating it by the factor $b+1$, you can get a $b$-separated Sidon set in $[0,L]$ of size $(1+o(1))\sqrt{L/(b+1)}$.

In general, the answer will depend heavily on the relation between $L$ and $b$. If $b$ is small as compared to $L$ (say, $b<\sqrt{L/2}$), then you can find a $b$-separated Sidon set $S\subset[0,L]$ of size about $\sqrt{L/2}$, as follows.

Let $q$ be a prime satisfying $2q^2\le L$ (this is the size of our set $S$, so we want to choose $q$ as large as possible subject to this condition). Fix a primitive root $g$ modulo $q$, and set
  $$ S := \{2qn+\nu(n)\colon 1\le n\le q-1 \}, $$
where $\nu(n)$ is the integer in the range $[0,q-2]$ such that $g^{\nu(n)}\equiv n\pmod q$.

Since $2q(n+1)>(2qn+q-2)+b$ (as it follows from $q\approx\sqrt{L/2}>b$), the set $S$ is $b$-separated.

To see that $S$ is Sidon, notice that 
  $$ (2qn_1+\nu(n_1))+(2qn_2+\nu(n_2)) = (2qn_3+\nu(n_3)) + (2qn_4+\nu(n_4)) $$ 
yields $n_1+n_2=n_3+n_4$, leading to $\nu(n_1)+\nu(n_2)=\nu(n_3)+\nu(n_4)$ and, consequently, to $n_1n_2\equiv n_3n_4\pmod q$. Thus, 
   $$ n_1+n_2 =n_3+n_4 $$
and
   $$ n_1n_2 \equiv n_3n_4\pmod q, $$
as a result of which $\{n_1,n_2\}=\{n_3,n_4\}$.

Comment: I start this routine verification and have troubles: if $dn+\nu(n)+dm+\nu(m)=dn_1+\nu(n_1)+dm_1+\nu(m_1)$, we get $\nu(n)+\nu(m)\equiv \nu(n_1)+\nu(m_1) \pmod{d}$, while I would prefer to have it modulo $q-1$...

Comment: @FedorPetrov: well, the only thing we really need is that the largest possible value of $\nu$ does not exceed $d/2$. Maybe, some parameters in my answer need to be adjusted; I will take care of it later today.

Comment: but for this $b$ should be greater than $q$ (or like that)

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I do not think so; we just have to define $d:=q-1+\max\{b,q-1\}$ instead of $d:=b+q-1$. Anyway, I have to leave now, will look closer later.

Comment: with such value of $d$ of course, but it yields sometimes the worse estimate for the diameter of $S$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: you are right, the bound is now a little weaker (roughly, $\sqrt{L/2}$ against $\sqrt{L}$).

Comment: @Seva Is the $\sqrt{L}$ bound tight? Is it possible to improve?

Comment: @Freeman: It is tight up to the coefficient: even if you do not insist the set to be separated ($b=0$), the size of a Sidon subset of $[0,L]$ does not exceed $(1+o(1))\sqrt L$.

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer is totally different from the one I posted several days ago, so I prefer to post it separately and not as a sort of an edit / appendix.)*

---

It is well known that the largest Sidon subset of the interval $[0,L]$ has size $(1+o(1))\sqrt  L$; see, for instance [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407117.pdf) by O'Bryant. Remarkably, if $b=o(\sqrt L)$, then you can find $b$-separated Sidon sets in $[0,L]$ of the same size $(1+o(1))\sqrt  L$; indeed, for any $b$, there is a $b$-separated Sidon set in $[0,L]$ of size at least $(1+o(1))\sqrt L-b$.

To see this, start with your favorite Sidon set $S\subset[0,L]$ (which, I expect, has size $|S|=(1+o(1))\sqrt L$). There is at most one pair of elements in $S$ at the distance $1$; remove one of them from $S$ and repeat the procedure with the distances $2,3,\dotsc,b$. You will have to remove $b$ elements at most, ending up with a $b$-separated subset of $S$ of size at least $|S|-b$.

Since any $b$-separated set in $[0,L]$ has size at most $L/(b+1)+1$, one cannot expect to have a lower bound of the order of magnitude $\sqrt L$ if $b$ is large as compared to $\sqrt L$. For a weaker bound, you can take a Sidon set $[0,L/(b+1)]$ and dilate it by the factor $b+1$; this way you get a $b$-separated Sidon set in $[0,L]$ of size $(1+o(1))\sqrt{L/(b+1)}$

Comment: Do you think there is reason to believe $b=o(L^{2/3})$ and $|S|=\Omega(\sqrt{L})$ is possible?

Comment: @Freeman: As you state it, this is certainly possible, just take $b=1$. I guess this is not what you really had in mind.

Comment: $b=\omega(L^{2/3-\epsilon})$ at any fixed $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Freeman: What is that $\omega$ notation?

Comment: Please take notation $\Omega$.

Comment: @Freeman:for $\epsilon<1/6$, you cannot have $b=\Omega(L^{2/3}-\epsilon)$ and $|S|=\Omega(\sqrt L)$, see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Freeman: I found it very technical and difficult to understand. If you want people to look at it, you should find a way to restate it in a clear, non-technical way, avoiding heavy notation and keeping the number of parameters to a minimum.

Comment: Made changes could you look https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320765/number-of-b-separated-sidon-sets-with-pairwise-difference-set-intersection-bou?